# Self-modifying code on Darwin 10.15 resulting in "malformed mach-o image"?

Tags: macos, dyld, mach-o, malformed, self-modifying

I have a program that generates self-modifying code (see https://tigress.wtf/selfModify.html in case you're interested). It runs on x86 Darwin and Linux. On Darwin, I compile with

```
gcc -g -segprot __TEXT rwx rwx self_modifying.c -o self_modifying.exe
```

Recently, this seems not to work, I get

```
dyld: malformed mach-o image: __TEXT segment maps start of file but is writable
```

when I run the program.

I'm running clang version 6.0.1 on MacOS 10.15.3. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

@AlexDenisov is pretty close, but the restriction does not apply only to executables running on Catalina with min macOS 10.15.0 and higher.

There are 2 formats of Mach-O load command that indicate the min MacOS the executable itself can use:
 - `LC_BUILD_VERSION`(the new one introduced around 10.14 if I recall correctly)
 - `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` (the legacy one)

Even with fallbacking to older MacOS version using `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX`:

```
gcc -segprot __TEXT rwx rwx -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 self_modifying.c
```

we run into the same problem.

To **bypass the check** one solution I found to work is to get rid of min macos version altogether. I'm not aware though of any `gcc` or `ld` flag that can achieve this. Fortunately we can do the processing after linking the executable with the help of Jonathan Levin's [jtool2](http://www.newosxbook.com/tools/jtool.html)

So the chain of commands become:

```
gcc -segprot __TEXT rwx rwx self_modifying.c 
jtool2 -l a.out                             
    LC 00: LC_SEGMENT_64             Mem: 0x000000000-0x100000000   __PAGEZERO
    LC 01: LC_SEGMENT_64             Mem: 0x100000000-0x100001000   __TEXT
        Mem: 0x100000f60-0x100000f83        __TEXT.__text   (Normal)
        Mem: 0x100000f84-0x100000f8a        __TEXT.__stubs  (Symbol Stubs)
        Mem: 0x100000f8c-0x100000fa6        __TEXT.__stub_helper    (Normal)
        Mem: 0x100000fa6-0x100000fb2        __TEXT.__cstring    (C-String Literals)
        Mem: 0x100000fb4-0x100000ffc        __TEXT.__unwind_info    
    LC 02: LC_SEGMENT_64             Mem: 0x100001000-0x100002000   __DATA_CONST
        Mem: 0x100001000-0x100001008        __DATA_CONST.__got  (Non-Lazy Symbol Ptrs)
    LC 03: LC_SEGMENT_64             Mem: 0x100002000-0x100003000   __DATA
        Mem: 0x100002000-0x100002008        __DATA.__la_symbol_ptr  (Lazy Symbol Ptrs)
        Mem: 0x100002008-0x100002010        __DATA.__data   
    LC 04: LC_SEGMENT_64             Mem: 0x100003000-0x100004000   __LINKEDIT
    LC 05: LC_DYLD_INFO             
           Rebase info: 8     bytes at offset 12288 (0x3000-0x3008)
           Bind info:   24    bytes at offset 12296 (0x3008-0x3020)
        No Weak info
           Lazy info:   16    bytes at offset 12320 (0x3020-0x3030)
           Export info: 48    bytes at offset 12336 (0x3030-0x3060)
    LC 06: LC_SYMTAB                
    LC 07: LC_DYSYMTAB              
            1 local symbols at index     0
            2 external symbols at index  1
            2 undefined symbols at index 3
           No TOC
           No modtab
            3 Indirect symbols at offset 0x30b8
    LC 08: LC_LOAD_DYLINKER         /usr/lib/dyld
    LC 09: LC_UUID                  UUID: 6AE91487-DB61-3FA8-8DBE-686FEC1DA8FC
    LC 10: LC_BUILD_VERSION         Build Version:           Platform: MacOS 10.15.0 SDK: 10
    LC 11: LC_SOURCE_VERSION        Source Version:          0.0.0.0.0
    LC 12: LC_MAIN                  Entry Point:             0xf60 (Mem: 0x100000f60)
    LC 13: LC_LOAD_DYLIB            /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    LC 14: LC_FUNCTION_STARTS       Offset:     12384, Size:      8 (0x3060-0x3068)
    LC 15: LC_DATA_IN_CODE          Offset:     12392, Size:      0 (0x3068-0x3068)
jtool2 -rc 10 --inplace a.out
```

Now your `a.out` should launch correctly :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are observing is the restriction of macOS Catalina and not related to your compiler.

Looking at the dyld source code (can be found here https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-1015.html) the error message is coming from this code:

```
if ( (segCmd->initprot & VM_PROT_WRITE) == VM_PROT_WRITE ) {
  if ( context.strictMachORequired )
    dyld::throwf("malformed mach-o image: %s segment maps start of file but is writable", segCmd->segname);
}
```

The exception is thrown only when `strictMachORequired`, which is always `true` on macOS 10.15 or higher, based on the other snippet from the dyld sources:

```
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
  gLinkContext.strictMachORequired = false;
  // <rdar://problem/22805519> be less strict about old macOS mach-o binaries
  ((dyld3::MachOFile*)mainExecutableMH)->forEachSupportedPlatform(^(dyld3::Platform platform, uint32_t minOS, uint32_t sdk) {
    if ( (platform == dyld3::Platform::macOS) && (sdk >= DYLD_PACKED_VERSION(10,15,0)) ) {
      gLinkContext.strictMachORequired = true;
    }
  });
  if ( gLinkContext.iOSonMac )
    gLinkContext.strictMachORequired = true;
#else
  // simulators, iOS, tvOS, watchOS, are always strict
  gLinkContext.strictMachORequired = true;
#endif
```