# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed when trying to static link a dylib in swift

Tags: swift, macos, frameworks, dylib, mach-o

I built a dylib file using fpcupdeluxe in freepascal with just a single cdecl _test function exposed on both
1) MacOS and
2) Debian (cross compiled to x86_64 darwin)

I tried calling dylib using 
1) dlopen
2) Bridging header
3) Framework

The dylib compiled on MacOS worked with all 3 methods. However when I replaced that dylib with the one I crosscompiled on debian, only dlopen seems to work, the other 2 methods using bridging header and framework gave me this error: 
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _test

I did an nm -gU on both dylib and only the relative virtual address of the _test function is different, what can I do to investigate the cause of this and solve it?

otool -L for the

Non-working

XXXXX.dylib:
    /home/wire/fpcupdeluxe/projects/XXXXX.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1404.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1252.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1253.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)

Working

/Users/wire/XXXXX.dylib:
    /Users/wire/XXXXX.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.100.1)

Where XXXXX is my library name, I have also noticed the path is different for the working and non working one. In the non-working one, my dylib points to the directory on my linux machine that is not supposed to be present on the mac. I have also tried to cross compile on windows and the path was in C:\ and the error was image not found, do I have to change that path? I'm new to MacOS programming

Comment: You should diff the dylib binaries with tools like otool, jtool or if you prefer UI tools MachOExplorer or MachOTool to inspect and compare the Mach-O load commands.

Comment: Good. I recommend removing the `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` for AppKit and Foundation from the dylib binary that your Debian cross compiler chain produces. You can achieve this using method I described in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60497896/self-modifying-code-on-darwin-10-15-resulting-in-malformed-mach-o-image/60505259#60505259 `jtool2` is available both on MacOS and Linux. By doing this you should at least learn if those extra frameworks are the culprit or it's something else

Comment: I removed the LC_LOAD_DYLIB as per the post but when I do otool -L again, I get
 truncated or malformed object (load command 2 fileoff field plus filesize field in LC_SEGMENT_64 extends past the end of the file)

./jtool2 -L produces
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)

and my xcode fails to build ;(

Comment: could you include all load commands for both dylibs for comparison? The more information you provide the bigger chance someone can help.

Comment: The only LC_LOAD_DYLIB that I excluded was my own dylib

Comment: I just updated my answer

Comment: you need to use a relative path not an absolute path

Comment: How would I go about changing it both in the cross compiled dylib and in my project settings?

Comment: https://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2018/12/05/rpath-what/

Comment: Thanks, will look into it

Comment: Alright that did the job, many thanks, wish I could give you more rep points :)

Comment: please post solution that solve your problem as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kamil.S, I found the solution that I just had to run install_name_tool -id @rpath/ to set it to a relative path since unlike in windows all paths to dynamic libraries are stored in the mach-o structure itself

Comment: Check out the `copy_dylibs.py` script in this [git repo](https://github.com/trojanfoe/xcodedevtools) which should do all the `install_name_tool` shenanigans for you.